# Reset ng-view content

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

I have a problem about to "reset" the ng-view content.
The situation is the following:

- index.html contains the ng-view
- the URL localhost/page points to page.html (connected to the ng-view in index.html) containing ng-switch to display the right partial page in relation to the link clicked (let's say the links available are subpage1 and subpage2)
- subpage1 and subpage2 contain a form each one with a couple of inputs

Now, if I type something in an input box of subpage1, then I switch on subpage2 and then back to subpage1, that input box still contains what I typed previously.
I would like that every time I switch between the subpages, they would get as thay are in beginning ("reset"/"reloaded"). How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

I think ui-router helps you better for this. You can use nested states there and define your `page` as a state and `.subpage1` will become `/page/subpage1/`.

The downside of this is that it will reload view and controller each time you enter the state but it will refresh your data.

If you wish to continue with the ng-view just reset the model manually from the controller once the desired action is triggered. In your case when you switch to `subpage2` just reset the model for `subpage1`